# Pass one object result to another object function like chain

Tags: javascript, object, math, return

I have one simple object calculation function .I was pass the object resultant data in to another object function like the chain reaction

***example like:***

`str.replace().replace().replace()`  They will pass the resultant data of first replace to 2nd replace like the chain reaction.

So i want to created the below code .But not working in my case .

See the below **snippet**

```js
var m=function(data){
  return {
       str :data,
       plus:function(b){
            this.str = this.str+b;
           return this.str;
         },
      min:function(a){
            this.str = this.str-a
            return this.str;
         }
    }
  }

console.log(m(5).plus(1).min(3))
```

If `5` add with `1` is `6` .Then pass the `6` into `min()` function for reduce `3` .finally console.log result `3` .But It have some here .Please help to solve my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use an object and return that object after a method call. For better use, you could implement [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) and [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) methods to use the return value directly.

What you need is to return the whole object, for all methods which a chainable.

```js
var m = function(value){
    var obj = {
            value: value,
            plus: function (b) {
                obj.value += b;
                return obj;
            },
            min: function(a) {
                obj.value -= a;
                return obj;
            },
            toString: function () { return obj.value; },
            valueOf: function () { return obj.value; }
        }
        return obj;
    }

console.log(m(5).plus(1).min(3).value);
alert(m(5).plus(1).min(3));
console.log(m(3).plus(7) - m(5).min(1));
```

Comment: its ok .but its not like that `str.replace().replace()` .its not there any extension(`it means min(3).value[value] `). If any another way to create like this or is not possible? .

Comment: yes, you could extend for example `String` with a new prototype, like returning a string with something changed, like `replace`.

Comment: what means `value[value]`?

Comment: i no need `value`  in end of the function `console.log(m(5).plus(1).min(3).value);`  i need only with `console.log(m(5).plus(1).min(3));` that

Comment: please have a look at `alert`. it returns the value without calling the value property. it calls instead `toString` method.

Comment: Thanks .But i  have one doubt. Why is show only alert .not with in console.log()

Comment: i think its a feature of console not to call `toString` or `value Of` method. instead it returns the real content.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var m=function(data){
  return {
       str :data,
       plus:function(b){
            this.str = this.str+b;
           return this;
         },
      min:function(a){
            this.str = this.str-a
            return this;
         }
    }
  }

console.log(m(5).plus(1).min(3).str)
```

For creating chain like method calls you need to return 'this' from the function after which you want to the chain to continue

Answer (score 0):

Another closer way, we can return `this` separately, at initialisation, and every other method calls.

Doing it this way is a real chain, as `this` called in the `plus` and `min` function is the incoming object, it's not a recomposition.

We often see both styles.

```js
function m(n) {
  this.value = n.value
  this.plus = (n) => {this.value = this.value + n.value; return this}
  this.min = (n) => {this.value = this.value - n.value; return this}
  return this // Only at initialisation
}

console.log(m({value: 5}).plus({value: 1}).min({value: 3}).value)
```